# Не работает функция по событию(клик)

Tags: javascript

Друзья, всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в моём коде, почему он не работает? Скрипт подключен, тест вывода на экран работает, а по клику цвет параграфов не меняется на указанный(красный).

```js
let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

function setRed() {
  this.style.color = 'red';
}

for (let key of p) {
  key.onclick = setRed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>HTML&CSS - Изучение</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, libero vitae non ipsam, velit nesciunt quia aliquid, ullam cum atque quibusdam dolor exercitationem nemo recusandae rerum officia magni officiis aliquam praesentium neque modi eos optio
    deserunt eum? Natus numquam dolores aliquid. Harum laudantium consequuntur asperiores nostrum, dolore cumque eveniet consectetur.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore voluptatum cum quas quos corrupti rerum ex laboriosam atque? Numquam quia mollitia vitae pariatur ab, quas et laudantium nulla cum? Ratione aliquid atque tempore, saepe optio commodi possimus
    distinctio illo nesciunt nihil molestias soluta quidem nam ut exercitationem at? Perferendis, rerum.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi quos saepe, dolor nobis magnam officia illum quis similique, voluptas repellendus nihil, vitae non rerum. Earum accusantium libero cupiditate explicabo, aliquid laboriosam. Maiores aspernatur
    inventore magni, ex quam laboriosam ipsa unde nisi fuga et accusantium nesciunt. Ducimus sunt pariatur nisi doloribus?</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Внимательно смотрите где вы писали часть с js и где оно должно быть

Comment: Нет нет, то что от JavaScript'a у меня в отдельном .js файле, который успешно подключён и работает исправно, я это проверил обычным алертом в этом же скрипте. Двумя частями не получилось сюда вставить

Comment: Тогда и в вопросе у вас все работает.

Comment: Забавно, почему то в хроме через HTML страницу не работает, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Другие обработчики, блокировка скриптов, конфликтующие стили... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Отсюда сложно сказать

Answer (score 0):

при тесте вашего кода, у меня не возникло ошибок, но возникла мысль, что вы просто забыли поставить теги скрипта поэтому вот решение, которое у меня работает локально

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <title>HTML&CSS - Изучение</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, libero vitae non ipsam, velit nesciunt quia aliquid, ullam cum atque quibusdam dolor exercitationem nemo recusandae rerum officia magni officiis aliquam praesentium neque modi eos optio
    deserunt eum? Natus numquam dolores aliquid. Harum laudantium consequuntur asperiores nostrum, dolore cumque eveniet consectetur.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore voluptatum cum quas quos corrupti rerum ex laboriosam atque? Numquam quia mollitia vitae pariatur ab, quas et laudantium nulla cum? Ratione aliquid atque tempore, saepe optio commodi possimus
    distinctio illo nesciunt nihil molestias soluta quidem nam ut exercitationem at? Perferendis, rerum.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi quos saepe, dolor nobis magnam officia illum quis similique, voluptas repellendus nihil, vitae non rerum. Earum accusantium libero cupiditate explicabo, aliquid laboriosam. Maiores aspernatur
    inventore magni, ex quam laboriosam ipsa unde nisi fuga et accusantium nesciunt. Ducimus sunt pariatur nisi doloribus?</p>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

  function setRed() {
    this.style.color = 'red';
  }

  for (let key of p) {
    key.onclick = setRed;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Нет нет, то что от JavaScript'a у меня в отдельном .js файле, который успешно подключён и работает исправно, я это проверил обычным алертом в этом же скрипте

Comment: Здесь двумя отдельными частями кода не получилось вставить

Comment: Хотя у Вас, вставляя скрипт непосредственно в HTML код всё работает, в чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```js
function colorRed() {
  let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

  function setRed() {
    this.style.color = 'red';
  }

  for (let key of p) {
    key.onclick = setRed;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', colorRed);
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, libero vitae non ipsam, velit nesciunt quia aliquid, ullam cum atque quibusdam dolor exercitationem nemo recusandae rerum officia magni officiis aliquam praesentium neque modi eos optio
  deserunt eum? Natus numquam dolores aliquid. Harum laudantium consequuntur asperiores nostrum, dolore cumque eveniet consectetur.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore voluptatum cum quas quos corrupti rerum ex laboriosam atque? Numquam quia mollitia vitae pariatur ab, quas et laudantium nulla cum? Ratione aliquid atque tempore, saepe optio commodi possimus
  distinctio illo nesciunt nihil molestias soluta quidem nam ut exercitationem at? Perferendis, rerum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi quos saepe, dolor nobis magnam officia illum quis similique, voluptas repellendus nihil, vitae non rerum. Earum accusantium libero cupiditate explicabo, aliquid laboriosam. Maiores aspernatur
  inventore magni, ex quam laboriosam ipsa unde nisi fuga et accusantium nesciunt. Ducimus sunt pariatur nisi doloribus?</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Проблему решил, оказывается скрипт нужно подключать после body, скрипт заработал